# How to get the position (top, left) of a WebPart in Sharepoint using c#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, position, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

How to get the position (top and left) of each WebPart in the Sharepoint (.aspx file) using c# code.

1- I have tried to export each WebPart as .xml file, but the top and left elements are empty.

2- I tried to loop over all web parts (type: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart) in the file using SPLimitedWebPartManager; there is no attributes for the top and left parameters, only the height and width are specified.

I am using Sharepoint-2013

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)